# FreeBSD 10.2 - Is three-way HAST replication possible?

Tags: freebsd, storage, cluster, high-availability

I have a pair of FreeBSD 10.2 servers using HAST to keep a volume replicated between them. I'm introducing two new storage nodes that have much newer hardware and will eventually replace the existing servers but I want to introduce replication gradually without disrupting the existing setup.

I'm attempting to use a configuration like this:

```
# /etc/hast.conf
# HAST - Highly Available Storage


compression     lzf
checksum       crc32
timeout         10
replication     memsync


resource ha0 {
        # new storage node #1
        on zsan1 {
                local /dev/zvol/vmdata/targets/ha0
                remote 10.10.30.11
                remote 10.10.30.12
                remote 10.10.30.14
        }
        # new storage node #2
        on zsan2 {
                local /dev/zvol/vmdata/targets/ha0
                remote 10.10.30.11
                remote 10.10.30.12
                remote 10.10.30.13
        }
        # old storage node #1
        on zfs-primary {
                local /dev/zvol/tank/targets/ha0
                remote 10.10.30.12
                remote 10.10.30.13
                remote 10.10.30.14
        }
        # old storage node #2
        on zfs-secondary {
                local /dev/zvol/tank/targets/ha0
                remote 10.10.30.11
                remote 10.10.30.13
                remote 10.10.30.14
        }
}
```

I have created new volumes to test the replication with this configuration on the new servers and the existing ones but when i run hastctl on the primary node it only shows a single 'remoteaddr':

```
root@zsan1:~ # hastctl list
ha0:
  role: primary
  provname: ha0
  localpath: /dev/zvol/vmdata/targets/ha0
  extentsize: 2097152 (2.0MB)
  keepdirty: 64
  remoteaddr: 10.10.30.14
  replication: memsync
  status: degraded
  workerpid: 7229
  dirty: 3424649216 (3.2GB)
  statistics:
    reads: 1649
    writes: 26117
    deletes: 0
    flushes: 27
    activemap updates: 1651
    local errors: read: 0, write: 0, delete: 0, flush: 0
    queues: local: 0, send: 0, recv: 0, done: 0, idle: 255
```

I would appreciate it if someone could help me out here, either what I'm doing is unsupported or I'm doing it wrong. Thank you!